# Google Form File Upload - Change file name to match form value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form for contact information. The form asks for Given Name (`col A`), Family Name (`col B`) and a File Upload restricted to images only (`col D`). I have a formula which displays the Full Name [Given Name] [Family Name] in `col C`.

When the form uploads the image files it keeps their original file name, however, I would like to change each uploaded file name to match the Full Name value in `col C`.

Couldn't find a way to do it and I suspect it would require a script?

Comment: you mean rename it before it comes to the sheet?

Comment: rename could take place even after it is uploaded.

The google form generates a URL with an ID value for each file uploaded. Ideally, i'd like to use the id of each file uploaded in col D to locate the file and change its name to the value in col C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, renaming an uploaded file could be done by using a script and it should be used if you want that file name changes on form submission.

- You will require to use the Driver Service or the Drive Advanced Service.
- You could use an `onFormSubmit` trigger to do this when the response is submitted but you could do the file name change at other time.
  NOTE: There are two `onFormSubmit` triggers, one for projects bounded to Forms and other projects bounded for Spreadsheets.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Answer (score 0):

You might create your own apps script for your form as correctly answered [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%C3%A9n) [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126525/google-form-file-upload-change-file-name-to-match-form-value/133431#133431).

If you are not a developer, you can use my [Form Uploads Manager](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/form_uploads_manager/756774028129) add-on for Google Forms available in the Google Workspace Marketplace to rename uploaded files, move them to any Google Drive specific folder or based on the form input. Another useful option: add a description for each uploaded file, which makes it easy to find files using the built-in Google Drive search.
Find add-on instructions on the [add-on home page](https://apps.myrout.es/fum).

Set "Rename uploads" field in the add-on Settings as following:
${Given Name} ${Family Name}
To keep the original file name and add the suffix you requested:
${UPLOAD.NAME} ${Given Name} ${Family Name}

You might decide not to rename uploads but put uploads from every submitter into an individual folder. In the add-on settings for uploads just add subfolder ${Given Name} ${Family Name}.